# "tax cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: eclipse

I am in the process of debugging. The code is supposed to take the cost and calculate the new price. I'm not sure what I am missing.

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
        public class DebugTwo4 {
        public static void main(String[] args) { 

          String costString;
          /* added semicolon */
          double cost;
          final double TAX = 0.06;
          costString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter price of item you are buying", "Purchases",
             JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          cost = Double.parseInt(costString);
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"With " + tax * 100 +
             "% tax,  purchase  is $" + (cost - cost * tax));
       }


}
```

Comment: TAX not tax. Java is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

**Java IS case-senstive.**

Change 'tax' to 'TAX'.

```
// old: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"With " + tax* 100 + "% tax,  purchase  is $" + (cost - cost * tax));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"With " + TAX * 100 + "% tax,  purchase  is $" + (cost - cost * TAX));
```